# Update database from multiple input values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a permissions table and I want the ability to check each multiple boxes and a modal window opens with the input fields to edit the permission name. Once I submit I want to update the database with the new names of each input.

Here is what I have so far...

For each box checked I out put this in the modal:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Permission Name</label>
<input class="del-'+row.id+' form-control" id="name['+row.name+']" type="text" name="name['+row.id+']" value="'+row.name+'" >
<input class="del-'+row.id+' form-control" id="id['+row.name+']" type="hidden" name="id['+row.id+']" value="'+row.id+'" >
</div>
```

Here is what the JS code looks like for the above:

```
$("#editModalForm").append('<div class="form-group"><label>Permission Name</label><input class="del-'+row.id+' form-control" id="name['+row.name+']" type="text" name="name['+row.id+']" value="'+row.name+'" ><input class="del-'+row.id+' form-control" id="id['+row.name+']" type="hidden" name="id['+row.id+']" value="'+row.id+'" ></div>');
```

Here is the PHP code when I submit the form:

```
//Update permission level names
$permissionId = $_POST['id'];
if($permissionDetails['name'] != $_POST['name']) {
    $permission = trim($_POST['name']);
    $previousName = $permissionDetails['name'];

    //Validate new name
    if (permissionNameExists($permission)) {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PERMISSIONNAME_IN_USE", array($permission));
    } elseif (minMaxRange(1, 50, $permission)) {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PERMISSION_CHAR_LIMIT", array(1, 50));    
    } else {
        if (updatePermissionNames($permissionId, $permission)) {
            $successes[] = lang("PERMISSION_NAME_UPDATE", array($previousName, $permission));
        } else {
            $errors[] = lang("SQL_ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the function that updates the database:

```
//Change a multiple permission level names
function updatePermissionNames($id, $name) {
global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;
$i = 0;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".$db_table_prefix."permissions
    SET name = ?
    WHERE
    id = ?
    LIMIT 1");
foreach($id as $ids) {
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $name, $ids);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close(); 
return $result; 
}
```

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong here so I am hoping someone can help me out. If you have any examples that would be great. Again, I want to know how I can update each value?

Comment: What are you trying to concatenate in your HTML attribute values? That's not JavaScript.

Comment: `$_POST['name']` will be an array, not a string.

Comment: I didn't post the full JS code. Just added it for reference.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get value of input with **name="id['+row.id+']"** 
you should do use

```
$arrID = $_POST['id']
foreach($arrID as $key => $value){
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
}
```

because input id[1] is array when post to server, itn't string.